# flex return rowIndex from button in datagrid component

Tags: apache-flex, datagrid, return, components, row

Hi I am trying to pass the rowindex when I click on a button in a row, the data value returns the correct information but the rowIndex returns nothing.

```
<mx:AdvancedDataGridColumn headerText="EDIT" showDataTips="false" editable="true">
    <mx:itemRenderer>
      <fx:Component>
            <mx:HBox horizontalAlign="center" verticalAlign="middle">
        <s:Button label="Edit" id="editGeo" click="{outerDocument.onClick(data, rowIndex)}"/>
        </mx:HBox>
    </fx:Component>
    </mx:itemRenderer>
</mx:AdvancedDataGridColumn>
```

thanks !

Answer (score 0):

I'm surprised you're provided code does not throw an error.

You need to access [listData](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/mx/controls/advancedDataGridClasses/AdvancedDataGridItemRenderer.html#listData).[rowIndex](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/mx/controls/listClasses/BaseListData.html#rowIndex).  listData should be an instance of the [AdvancedDataGridListData](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/mx/controls/advancedDataGridClasses/AdvancedDataGridListData.html) class.

```
<s:Button label="Edit" id="editGeo" click="{outerDocument.onClick(data, listData.rowIndex)}"/>
```

Since the HBox does not have a listData property, you may have to implement it on your own for the data to be passed in.  Something like this should suffice:

```
[Bindable]
public var listData:BaseListData;
```

It has been a while since I've been deep into an MX component, so my memory is a bit rusty on the last part.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the first answer, try not to use listData.rowIndex when your datagrid has the vertical scroll bar, because the rowIndex just shows the index of current visible Rows.

Try to use the current object index in the DataProvider of the datagrid instead.